# Removing Sys-V-Init script in favour of rc.local. Will application still shutdown correctly?

Tags: scripts, shutdown, startup, sysv

I've had to remove the `/etc/init.d/crashplan` script by doing `update-rc.d -f crashplan remove` in favour of starting the daemon using `/etc/rc.local` (the reason for this is that I have an encrypted home dir that only gets mounted upon user login, and this is causing the backup daemon some issues during boot, see [here](http://blog.nozav.org/post/2011/06/30/How-to-use-CrashPlan-with-an-encrypted-home-folder) for more details).

This all seems to work pretty work for starting the service only after login, but what I'm wondering is if Crashplan will still shutdown correctly on system reboot or halt without the sys-v-init script links in `/etc/rcN.d`?

To be honest, when I did the `update-rc.d -f crashplan remove` only a startup script from `/etc/rc2.d` was removed anyway, which makes me think it's probably fine. However,I just wanted to check I should be putting kill symlinks in the 0,1,6 runlevel dir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I should still keep the Sys-V-init kill links at the 0,1,6 runlevels:

```
update-rc.d crashplan stop 20 0 1 6
```

so that it still shutsdown correctly on shutown/recovery/reboot.